# How do I pick only the column I require using python

Tags: python, arrays, machine-learning, data-science

```
ml = MonkeyLearn('2d14ec2555abc7f9e2aefee982e212d9091e310a')
data = ['I am excellent']
result = ml.classifiers.classify(model_id, data)
t = result.body[0]
print(t)

{'text': 'Good', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id': 122921383, 'confidence': 0.983}]}
```

I have a List in array Array, how can i remove only 'classification' column from this data, This data is in array and I want only the
Desired output:

```
Classification : Tag_name : Positive 
                 Confidence : 0.983
```

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code -

```
t = {'text': 'Good', 'external_id': None, 'error': False, 'classifications': [{'tag_name': 'Positive', 'tag_id': 122921383, 'confidence': 0.983}]}
classifications = t['classifications']
```